# Functions Using Double List in Haskell

Tags: haskell, arraylist

I am trying to learn Haskell, and I cannot find a solution to the following problem.

Consider the following function with type `ourFunction :: [[String]] -> [[String]]`.
When two adjoint strings are the same, they should change to `'x'`.
Example:

```
ourFunction[["a","b","c","d"],[["e","f","a","d"]
```

> `a` `b` `c` `d`
>   `e` `f` `a` `d`

It should return `[["a","b","c","x"],[["e","f","a","x"]`.

I ask this to understand list indexing and changing a value within a list in a function.

Comment: I presume i should use this "map (\x -> if p x then f x else x) xs" for changing the values that i want, but the thing is how can i create the condition. I mean how can i find 2 adjoints "d" in the example above.

Comment: Is it always only 2 lists of strings?

Comment: no it may be more than 2

Comment: What should `[["a"],["a"],["a"]]` return? `[["x"],["x"],["a"]]` , `[["a"],["x"],["x"]]`, or `[["x"],["x"],["x"]]` ? And what about `[["a"],["a"],["b"]]` ? Should it be `[["x"],["x"],["b"]]` ? or left as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming equally long lists within

```
import Data.List

test = replaceWithxForEqualIndexes [["a","b","c","d"],["e","f","a","d"]]
--Here is the magic, transpose so you get same indexes in the same list,
--then check for equality and replace if equals, then transpose back
replaceWithxForEqualIndexes x = transpose $ map ifSameChangeToX $ transpose x

ifSameChangeToX x = ifSameChangeTo x "x"

ifSameChangeTo :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
ifSameChangeTo x rep
    | allTheSame x = take (length x) (repeat rep)
    | otherwise = x

allTheSame :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame xs = and $ map (== head xs) (tail xs)
```

Comment: I think in general in Haskell you generally don't need to worry about indexes too much:)

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.List

ourFunction :: [[String]] -> [[String]]
ourFunction input = [fst result, snd result]
  where result = unzip $ zipWith (\x y -> if x == y then ("x", "x") else (x, y)) (head input) (last input)
```